# Pass Link-Button Click from One User Control to Another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have two user controls on the same page. One contains a ListView that displays navigation links, the second user control should be updated when user clicks on the buttonlink in the ListView. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. UserControl A should handle the button-click and [raise a custom event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx) declared in the UserControl
2. The page handles this event and calls a public method of UserControl B that updates it's content

You could pass necessary informations from UserControl A to page via EventArgs(or pass the UserControl itself as argument and use it's public properties).

The page then passes the arguments to UserControl B via method parameter or by changing it's public properties before calling the `Update`-Method.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx
- http://chiragrdarji.blogspot.com/2007/08/raise-event-from-user-control-to-main.html

---

Here is the sample code you've requested. 
Sorry for the meaningless naming but you haven't told what's this all about. You should use readable variables,properties,method and event-names instead.

Reduced **UserControl A** with a ListView:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UsercontrolA.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.UserControlA" %>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
        CommandName="LinkClick" 
        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' 
        runat="server" 
        Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Removed the ListView databinding from codebehind because that doesn't matter. The important part is handling the ListView's ItemCommand and raising the custom event:

```
Public Event LinkClicked(sender As UserControlA, id As Int32)

Private Sub LV_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "LinkClick" Then
        Dim id = CType(e.CommandArgument, Int32)
        ' This is the best way for UC's to commmunicate with the page: '
        RaiseEvent LinkClicked(Me, id)
    End If
End Sub
```

Simple **UserControl B** with nothing more than a Label(ascx):

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UserControlB.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.UserControlB" %>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

With an `Update`-Method in codebehind:

```
Public Sub Update(showID As Int32)
    Me.Label1.Text = String.Format("Link {0} clicked", showID.ToString)
End Sub
```

Finally, here is the **Page**(aspx)

```
<uc1:UsercontrolA ID="UC_A" runat="server" />
<br />
<uc2:UserControlB ID="UC_B" runat="server" />
```

It controls both UserControls. It handles the event from UserControl A and calls the `Update`-Method that UserControl B provides:

```
Private Sub LinkClicked(sender As UserControlA, id As Integer) Handles UC_A.LinkClicked
    Me.UC_B.Update(id)
End Sub
```

The **advantage** of this event-approach is that UserControls stay being reusable. You can use UserControl A in other pages as well even when they don't handle this event. It's part of the controller to decide what is needed and what should be done.

UserControls as a rule should not depend on specific controllers, otherwise they are hard-linked and not reusable. That would be also a good source for nasty erros. A UserControl might be a controller for other nested (User-)Controls but not for the page itself.

**Communication Summary**:

- Page -> UserControl -> public properties and methods
- UserControl -> Page -> Events
- UserControl -> UserControl -> the controller-UserControl adopts the page-role(see above)

Comment: Is it possible to supply some sample code I'm really struggling trying to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron: You're welcome. Just added an explanation for this approach.